# anchor background image - anchor text overlaying image

Tags: css

I have the following CSS which displays a background image in the anchor.  The problem is that the link text is displaying over the image.  Any ideas?

```
a.interactive {
background:url(../images/icons/icon_interactive.png) left center no-repeat;
padding-right:50px;
display:inline-block;    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added padding-left which shifted the text over to the right...

```
a.interactive {
background:url(../images/icons/icon_interactive.png) left center no-repeat;
padding-left:30px;
height:25px;
width:25px;
display:inline-block;    
text-decoration: none;
vertical-align:text-center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the required padding-left? If the image is 30px do something like `padding-left:32px'` and it will push the text to the right of the image.